Можно ли считать файлы с одинаковым именем но разными типом формата подобием "перегрузки" файлов?
Допустим у меня есть 2 и более файлов с одиноковыми именем, но разными форматом данных:

file.txt
file.cpp
file.h
file.hpp
... и т.д.

Считается это "перегрузкой" файлов?

Показанные файлы имеют РАЗНЫЕ имена. То, что называют расширением - это на самом деле часть имени файла. Кстати, и точка - это тоже часть имени.

Для начала нужно определиться со значением термина "перегрузка файла". Если это вдруг означает придание имени файла того или иного расширения, тогда это как раз то, о чём вы спрашиваете. :-)
Если под "перегрузкой файла" понимать что-то аналогичное перегрузке оператора в c++/c# (и др. ЯП), то нет. Скорее, расширение файла определяет его тип (класс), в зависимости от которого ОС перегружает процедуру (оператор) открытия файла.

"Если под "перегрузкой файла" понимать что-то аналогичное перегрузке оператора" - Почти. Я имел ввиду что-то типо перегрузкой имён функций (хотя ваш ответ может тоже имел это ввиду). Где могу быть одинаковые имена, но разные принимаемые аргументы, точно так же как у файлов разные имена, но разные типы файлов.

Нет, в вашем случае, каждый файл имеет уникальное расширение, которое указывает на тип содержимого файла. Эти расширения помогают операционной системе и программам определить, как обрабатывать файл.
Поэтому это не будет являться перезагрузкой.
